# How to check if you actually got an result from your aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When my aggregate finds nothing and data is [] then it still resolves my function.

How can I check if my aggregate actually found something?

my `if (!data) {`is not working

```
usersTable.aggregate (
    {
        $match:{
            _id: UserID
        }
    }
,function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error('findUser: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log("found: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        if (!data) {
            throw new Error('ERR: Unknown userID in call of newBooking');
        }
        resolve("OK");
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you using mongodb, and if so, which version?

Comment: Newest version 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this, `if (!data) {` will never work because even when mongo returns an empty object, its still an object.

Instead I found this function

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

So now I can use `if (isEmpty(data)) {` and it works perfectly.